# Entity Framework Include - Returns NULL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to load related entities with EF with a single DB Call (Eager Loading), to achieve this I am trying to use include statement as below.

```
var db = _DbContext;
     var r1 = await
                db.Request.Where(r => idList.Contains(r.RequestId))
                .Include(r => r.RequestedService)
                ...more include
                ...more include
                ...more include
                .ToListAsync();
```

When I am running it with include statements I get a single item with null returned, however if I run it without include it gives the entity back. After the above statement if I add below condition for null check I get back the entity.

```
if(r1.HasAny() && r1[0] == null)
{
    r1 =
    await
        db.Request.Where(r => idList.Contains(r.RequestId)).ToListAsync();
}
```

What could be the reason's when adding an include can change the return? I have the navigational properties set to virtual and public.

Adding Entities

```
public class Request : BaseEntity
{
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long RequestId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<RequestedService> RequestedService { get; set; }
}


public class RequestedService : BaseEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long RequestedServiceId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long RequestId { get; set; }
    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
}
public class RequestDbContext : DbContextBase
{
    public object SyncObject = new object();

    public RequestDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<RequestDbContext>(null);
    }

    public RequestDbContext(string connectionStringName) : base(string.Empty)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<RequestDbContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Request> Request { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<RequestedService> RequestedService { get; set; }

    public class RequestDbContextInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<RequestDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(RequestDbContext context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried incrementally introducing the included relations? On a hunch I'd be looking at a faulty FK declaration on a required relation. EF will apply these as an Inner Join and if it happens to be mapped to the wrong column this could lead to the primary record not coming back. (or in other cases, the wrong relative row coming back.)

Comment: Thanks @StevePy Yes, even if I try adding only single include, causes issue. Also, I have traced the queries generated and query is returning data correctly with proper join on the correct key.

Comment: That is curious... Can you put up the entity definitions and any configuration for the Request and the single Include scenario (assuming RequestedService) that this definitely occurs with?

Comment: Added trimmed down version of the entities. I also realized I don't face this issue always for some requestId I get the entities returned correctly

Comment: Ok, I still would suspect a mismatched FK. One thing that I do see is that in RequestService (RequestSkill?) the RequestId should be marked with `[ForeignKey(Request)]` rather than `[Required]`. In the cases that the entities are returned correctly, check the referenced entities against your data, do they appear to be correct or associated against a different request?

Comment: .Include will not create inner joins, but rather left outer joins. However, I'd expect a swallowed SqlException in there, possibly due to not matching schema.

Comment: Thanks @StevePy and DevilSuichiro. As per steve's suggestion I have added the ForeignKey attribute that seems to have resolved the issue.